# getCheckedItemPositions() has a size of 0

Tags: android

I am trying to get the positions of the views from my listview but the size of the SparseBooleanArray is always 0.

This is the code from my activity.

```
IngredientIndivAdapter adapter;
ListView lv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_screen);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String prev_but = intent.getStringExtra("hi");

    ArrayList<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    list1.add("a");
    list1.add("b");
    list1.add("c");
    list1.add("d");
    list1.add("e");

    adapter = new IngredientIndivAdapter(this,list1);
    lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview1);
    lv.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

}

public void remove_ingredient_button(View v){
    SparseBooleanArray remove_list = lv.getCheckedItemPositions();
    Log.d("poo",""+remove_list.size());
    if(remove_list!=null)
    for(int i = 0; i < remove_list.size(); i++){
        if(remove_list.valueAt(i)){
            View remove_view = (View)findViewById(remove_list.keyAt(i));
            ((LinearLayout)remove_view.getParent()).removeView(remove_view);
        }
    }
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

This is the XML for that activity

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.JTA.recipeshoppinglist.ListScreen">

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">
    <ListView 
        android:id="@+id/listview1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ></ListView>
</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/add_b"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="#FFFF9900"
    android:text="+"
    android:onClick="add_button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/remove_item"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:text="-"
    android:onClick="remove_ingredient_button" />
```

This is my custom row XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/ingredient_check"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checkable="true"
        android:background="#FF0000" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And this is my custom array adapter.

```
public class IngredientIndivAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

static class ViewHolder{
    CheckBox text;
}

ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
Context context;
ViewHolder viewHolder;

public IngredientIndivAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> iList){
    super(context,R.layout.ingredient_row,iList);
    this.list=iList;
    this.context=context;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){


    if(convertView == null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ingredient_row, parent, false);

        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.text = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ingredient_check);

        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

    }
    else{
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }

    viewHolder.text.setText(list.get(position));
    return convertView;
}

public boolean hasStableIds(){
    return true;
}
}
```

Comment: Google search is friend: https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=getCheckedItemPositions&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SparseBooleanArray checked = listView.getCheckedItemPositions(); 
for (int i = 0; i < listview.getCount(); i++){

if(checked.get(i)==true) {

// do something 
} 
}
```

I hope it will work.